# Approach for statically allocating in a "common library" in embedded systems

Tags: c, allocation, static-memory-allocation

We have a common C library for several embedded systems, which all use static (i.e. compile time) allocation.

So, this means we usually have something which boils down to this (if we don't want to change the common source file):

```
#define TMR_MAX 100
int actual_number_of_timers;
SoftTimer softTimers[TMR_MAX];
```

In other words, to avoid malloc'ing, lots of space is actually wasted.

Or we can do this, which is to have a new set of enums for each project:

```
enum TimerType
{
    TMR_KEYBOARD = 0,
    TMR_LCD,
    ...,
    TMR_MAX
};

SoftTimer softTimers[TMR_MAX];
```

This other case doesn't waste space, but it means each project changes the (say) `timer.h` file in order to define its own constants. Btw, the timer example is just an example of the principle.

So is there a smarter way to have something like compile-time "just-the-right-size" allocation which will still allow us to have a common "frozen" codebase with separate tests?

Comment: You need a consultant/software architect. This is beyond what SO is for.

Comment: @Olaf I may be wrong, but the Help Center says "if your question generally covers .. a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development .. then you’re in the right place to ask your question!".

Comment: @SergeyB.: Yes, and a question might be **meant** to be withoin rules. But we are no clairvoyants, so what's writte counts, not whatever the author has in mind..

Comment: You can create project-specific versions of the `timers.h` header, or you can have the generic header include a project-specific header (e.g. `timers-project.h`) for the list of names. As long as each project defines `TMR_MAX`, it'll work. However, code that references the timers array by index number must be recompiled per project. That probably isn't much of a problem; you need to recompile the code anyway. Except that if there are references to a timer that isn't defined for a particular project, you need to make the code conditional on whether the timer is defined. That's hard with `enum`.

Answer (score 1):

Pass `TMR_MAX` as a macro flag to your compiler. For example for GCC that would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    printf ("%d\n", TMR_MAX);
}
```

`gcc main.c -DTMR_MAX=42 && ./a.out` gives `42`

Comment: That's one fairly common approach too. I am not sure why anyone would consider this answer "unhelpful".

Answer (score 1):

How flexible is your toolchain, in particular the link editor?  With the GNU toolchain and ELF targets, you could have individual timer variables (instead of an array) and put them into a specific section:

```
SoftTimer softTimers __attribute__ ((section ("alloc_timers")));
```

GNU `ld` will synthesize special `__start_alloc_timers` and `__stop_alloc_timers` symbols which you could use to iterate over the timers.  Of course, you would have to identify the timers by their variable names (or pointers) and could no longer use enum constants for that.

Comment: It's actually shared between several different compilers with some conditionals right now, but GCC is one of them, yes. We don't necessarily need enums, btw, the question is basically just about the allocation part.

Comment: Oh, it's more a matter of the link editor anyway. I expect that many C compilers either support section attributes, or at least offer a pragma to control variable placement or a command line option (so that you can control the section using separate compilation).

Answer (score 1):

Along the lines of [Sergey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45240053/2096401) move the definitions of `TMR_MAX` etc. out of the relevant header files, but instead of defining them on the command-line, you could have a `configuration.h` file that would be specific to each project:

```
// Configuration settings for project XYZ

#define TMR_MAX (3)
#define WIDGET_COUNT (23)
...
```

This would then be included in source files before all other headers:

```
// Widget-timing module for project XYZ

#include "configuration.h"
#include "timer.h"
#include "widget.h"
...
```